# Check Existance Of Entry In Model Within View File using Yii

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

This might sound kind of basic (and it probably is), but I've been trying to get this for a few hours now and either I need a break from coding or it just wont budge.

I have an active record variable which brings database entries from a model:

```
$variable = Model::model()->findAll();
```

So I have $variable available in my view file and I want to check for the existence of a specific entry within the results. I am using the primary key of an entry available in the `$variable`, but I can't seem to get it working.

What is the correct way to check if a given entry is contained within that variable from the view file, not the controller?

PS: I do not want to iterate through the result set, it wouldn't be very efficient for my application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right then:

- Indeed its better not to have such pieces of code in a view file.
- If you are forced to use CActiveRecord.fin*() methods, consider using findByPk($pk). If it returns null - no such record.
- Consider having your models extending [PcBaseArModel](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pcbasearmodel/) as that class has 'checkExists($pk)' method that looks natural in the check you need to perform. This base class has other goodies - check its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$data = Post::model()->findAllBySql("select * from tbl_post where id=".$data->id);
```

or

```
$post=Post::model()->find(array(
    'condition'=>'postID=:postID',
    'params'=>array(':postID'=>$data->id)
));
```